# Image Sequence Rendered Purple Despite Being Within Image Sequence Range

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, light, shader-nodes

I am trying to display a movie of 500 frames from a projector and have the image sequence of the frames called 0001.jpg to 0500.jpg all in the same folder. I have set up my image texture node with frames = 500, start frame = 1 and offset = 0. I have tried various combinations and scrolled through my preview and it's always purple on every frame. Is there anything else that could be going wrong here?

[image]

Edit: Blend File
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123787/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-image-sequence-rendered-purple-despite-being-w).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after a few days experimenting I can confirm this is a bug with version 2.83 and updating to 2.92 makes this blend file work as expected.

[image: Scene rendering as expected]